# Sorting strings ignoring case; uppercase first for equal strings

Tags: c

I have written such a piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int compare_str(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char * const * aa=a;
    char * const * bb=b;
    return strcasecmp(*aa, *bb);
}

int sort_alphabetically(char tab[])
{
    if(strlen(tab)<1 || tab[strlen(tab)-1]=='\n')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(tab); i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]=='-')
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int spaces_count=0;
    int first=0;
    int ch=0;
    for(unsigned int i=1; i<strlen(tab); i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]!=' ')
            first=1;
        if(tab[0]==' ' && tab[1]==' ')
            ch=1;
        if(tab[i]==' ' && tab[i+1]>=33 && tab[i+1]<=126 && first==1)
            spaces_count++;
    }
    int words_count=spaces_count+1;
    char **words=malloc(words_count * sizeof(char*));
    char *pch;
    int word_idx=0;
    pch=strtok(tab, " ");
    while(pch!=NULL)
    {
        words[word_idx++]=strdup(pch);
        pch=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    qsort(words, words_count, sizeof(char*), compare_str);
    for(int i=0; i<words_count; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<strlen(words[i]); j++)
        {
            if(ch==0)
                *(tab++)=words[i][j];
            else
                if(words[i][j]!=' ')
                {
                    *(tab++)=words[i][j];
                    ch=0;
                }
        }
        if(i!=words_count-1)
            *(tab++)=' ';
        else
            *(tab++)='\0';
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(tab); i++)
        if(tab[i]==' ' && tab[i+1]==' ')
            tab[i]='\0';
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char input[1000];
    printf("Enter text: ");
    if(fgets(input, 1000, stdin))
    {
        if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n')
            input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
        if(sort_alphabetically(input))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect input data");
            return 2;
        }
        else
            printf("%s", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It sorts alphabetically words inputted by user. The thing is it makes the job but I would also like it to check if the words are the same. If they are word with first capital letter should stay before the word with first small letter.
Ex.:

Enter text:

TeChnoLOGY iS TeAChiNg Us tO Be human aGAinSiMoN MainWARing IS

Output should be:

aGAinSiMoN Be human **IS iS** MainWARing TeAChiNg TeChnoLOGY tO Us

But it is:

aGAinSiMoN Be human **iS IS** MainWARing TeAChiNg TeChnoLOGY tO Us

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve, what you want, you have to change your comparison function slightly.
As you observed, `strcasecmp()` will put the order of two equal words indeterminate. So, if `strcasecmp()` deems two words equal (barring the case), you have to compare them case-sensitive (with the appropriate function, you'll guess which ;) and return that result. Otherwise, just return the result of `strcasecmp()`.

Comment: OK, thanks for help! Think I know what should do now.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function `compare_str` is a wrapper around `strcasecmp()`, which explicitly and specifically performs a case-insensitive comparison.  If you instead want a case-sensitive comparison then exchange that for a function that provides one, or write a replacement, or just add code to `compare_str` to differentiate more finely in the cases where `strcasecmp()` returns 0, depending on exactly what ordering you want.

Since the nature and details of the question lead me to suspect that this is an academic exercise, I leave it to you to work out the details.  The objective is that `compare_str()` must return a negative number if the first argument should be sorted before the second, a positive number if the second should be sorted before the first, or zero if either order is acceptable.

Comment: The case sensitive comparison function you (probably) mean would sort all upper-case words before their lowercase variants, which is not what the OP (or his teacher ;) wants.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So the way is to use case-sensitive function, yeah? But it don't want it to be fully case-sensitive, words with first capital letters shouldn't be at first always but only when two words are the same.

Comment: @geekon, I have expanded my comments a bit, but I am not going to write the code for you.  If the issue is that `strcasecmp()` is not discerning enough, so that the only problem with it is that it sometimes returns 0 when the answer you want is nonzero, then you don't have to take its result as your final answer.  You can perform a further analysis in those cases.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't mean to write it for me but the problem is now solved ;)